# Adding a empty line between each data set when merging

Tags: merge, sas

So right now I am merging 3 data sets together. I am just wondering if it is possible to add an empty line between each of the data sets to see them more clearly instead of all squished together.

Thank you

Comment: Yes,if you have all character variables try creating a dataset with the same columns and set all character variables to  " ". If you have numeric variables, I suppose zero would be the most equivalent. However, it might get you the same result by creating a new column data_label = "A" for the first dataset, and "B" and "C" for the others.

Comment: `merge`ing or `set`ing?  And where does this empty line really need to be - are you displaying this in output (`proc print` or similar)?

Comment: Hi guys, I am using proc report.

Comment: Can you provide an example in your question then?  Use `sashelp.class` dataset or something like that.

Comment: You aren't merging. If you want a line after each, look at the BREAK option for reporting.  `break after GROUPVAR/skip;`  where GROUPVAR is your variable that separates the sections based on a GROUP.